# Converting immutable to mutable map java

Tags: java, collections, immutability, mutable

I have an immutable map that I get from the method in another part. And when processing I want to delete a key from it and then use it further, the key is always on the map.

```java
ImmutableMap<String, Object> immutableMap = doSomethingAndGetImmutableMap();
        
// convert to mutable
Map<String, Object> newMutableMap =  ??
    
newMutableMap.remove("pin");
```

Is there any built-in method to do convert immutable to mutable map java? I saw there are several ways to do the opposite but not from immutable to mutable map.

I used Maps.newHashMap but is it the best and the most efficient way?

Comment: You probably have to copy the immutable map; e.g. new HashMap(immutableMap).  But which `ImmutableMap` interface are you talking about?  There isn't one in Java SE ... or Spring.  Are you talking about Guava?

Comment: ImmutableCollections$Map in SpringBoot.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a SpringBoot class.  Please provide the **full** class name so we can be sure we know what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a new `HashMap` from the existing `Map` using the copy constructor.

```
 HashMap<String, Object> = new HashMap<>(immutableMap);
```

Note that this is a brand new object.  There isn't a way to make an immutable map mutable.  That would be breaking abstraction.  I guess conceptually you could design mutable wrapper for an immutable map that stored the *changes* in a second (private) map structure.  But Guava doesn't appear to support that.

---

> Is this or `Maps.newHashMap` more performant?

Guava `Maps.newHashMap(map)` simply returns `new HashMap<>(map)`.  That call will be inlined by the JIT compile, so there should be zero performance difference on a modern JVM once the code has been JIT compiled.

You are almost certainly wasting your time micro-optimizing this kind of stuff:

- You should FIRST design and write the application code and get it to work.
- THEN you benchmark it.
- THEN you decide from the benchmark results if the application needs optimizing at all.
- THEN you profile it to determine where the performance hotspots are.
- THEN you optimize the performance hotspots.

Unless there is something really weird, following the above procedure would have lead to you not wasting your time asking this question.  To paraphrase<sup>1</sup> Donald Knuth:

> *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*.

---

<sup>1 ... and oversimplify / take out of context ...</sup>

Comment: Is this or Maps.newHashMap more performant?